# How to unit test variables on the parent scope when using controllerAs syntax in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controlleras, controlleras

I'm trying to unit test a controller in which I'm using Angular's `controllerAs` syntax. I also use this to access variables in the parent scope. For example, if the parent controller is called `parent`, and the child controller called `child`, then in the view of the child I do e.g. `ng-if="parent.model.age > 12"`.

Now, I want to unit test this. I created the controller in the unit test like this:

```
childController = $controller('ChildController', {
    $scope: scope
});
```

But as far as I can see, that doesn't allow me to access variables on ParentController? Is there a way to do that in Angular?